# How to create a responsive sidebar that goes to under the content on an breakpoint?

Tags: css, responsive-design, sidebar, flexbox

On the moment I have a sidebar.
Now it has to go to under the content when
you come on a breakpoint when you make the window of 
your browser smaller.

This is my css now:

```
aside{

width:20%;
float: right;
background-color: #B8B8B8;
margin-top: 2.8em;
margin-left: -1em;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

The rest of my content has a width of
79% and float left.

has anyone an idea how to get my sidebar under the content when 
I make my window smaller of the browser. So the sidebar has to be responsive 
when you see my website on an smartphone.

Answer (score 0):

with a media query

```
@media screen and (max-width: BREAKPOINT){
   aside, content{
     width: 100%;
     float: none;
   }
}
```

Just make sure The sidebar is placed underneath the content in HTML and it'll work

Comment: The sidebar is on top in the html in the body. But it is not necessarily to move the sidebar underneath the content. As long as it passes into the content and not remains a sidebar on the right side.

Comment: What I wrote there will display it at full-width and no longer be floated on the side. It is just a container.

If that's not what you want, could you maybe explain a bit further?

Comment: It has to be a full width after the breakpoint. On a desktop screen it has to be a sidebar on the right side. But when you see the website on a smartphone, you see not a sidebar on the right side but it is in the content. With the same width a the content

Comment: that's what the media query does. Have you tried it out?